# Apache/Subversion access: Allow access to all authenticated user except one

Tags: apache, svn

Is it possible to grant rw access to all authenticated users to a repository except one or two users?

```
[groups]
guest = paxclient

[repos:/]
* = rw #(but exclude members of guest group)

[repos:/cplusplus/ClientPAX/]
@guest = rw
```

I want people in guest group to have access to a certain url but they cant have access to the rest of the repository.

Is this possible today?